# Get WebServlet name from Class name

Tags: servlets

Is there a way to get the `@WebServlet` name of a `Servlet` by using the class name?

I have access to the `ServletContext` if that helps.

The class name is safer to use because it gets refactored if I change it.

I'm trying to get a Servlet's mappings as follows

```
String servletName = "someServlet"   
Collection<String> mappings = servletContext.getServletRegistration(servletName).getMappings();
```

But rather than simply hard coding a value for the `servletName` I would prefer to retrieve it safely from the `HttpServlet` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ServletContext`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/servletcontext) has another method which returns *all* servlet registrations: [`getServletRegistrations()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/servletcontext#getServletRegistrations--). The [`ServletRegistration`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/servletregistration) interface has in turn a [`getClassName()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/registration#getClassName--) method which is of your interest:

> `String getClassName()`
>
> Gets the fully qualified class name of the Servlet or Filter that is represented by this Registration.

So, this should do:

```java
Class<? extends HttpServlet> servletClass = YourServlet.class;
Optional<? extends ServletRegistration> optionalRegistration = servletContext
    .getServletRegistrations().values().stream()
    .filter(registration -> registration.getClassName().equals(servletClass.getName()))
    .findFirst();

if (optionalRegistration.isPresent()) {
    ServletRegistration registration = optionalRegistration.get();
    String servletName = registration.getName();
    Collection<String> servletMappings = registration.getMappings();
    // ...
}
```

The `servletName` is your answer. But as you can see, the mappings are readily available without the need for yet another `ServletContext#getServletRegistration()` call with the `servletName`.